# Memtest 86 for my laptop errors 'memtest86 unexpected interrupt halting cpu0'

Tags: windows-7, memtest86+

Any ideas what could be wrong in this instance. My laptop has refused to take new Win 7 Operating system, I get blue screen errors. The previous Os on the laptop was Vista Home Edition, which became unstable and crashed (blue screen of death) regulary.

I tried to run memtest86, I get the error message above.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much means that the ram is likely to be faulty. Both windows versions BSODing might be due to this too.

Breaking it down a little more 'cpu0' is your 'first' processor. Your memory is acting in an unexpected way, and apparently memtest itself is crashing due to this, or simply failing the memory - the more typical output looks like

> Unexpected Interrupt - Halting CPU0 (Test #2 failed at 16% with four errors)

So there should also be an indication of failed test from memtest in addition to that error i believe.

Any errors at all from memtest is a bad thing (tm)